# What is the difference between these 3 type of negation?

Tags: negation

What is the difference between these three types of negation?

> Weitere Periodstarte sind nicht möglich.
>
> Weitere Periodstarte sind unmöglich.
>
> Keine weiteren Periodstarte sind möglich.

Are all the sentences grammatically correct? What are the differences in meaning?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I never heard the word "Peroidstart" in German, they seem correct.

Comment: What is "Periodstart" supposed to mean? The compound substantive seems to have been constructed the wrong way.

Comment: @Dirk Liebhold: Even if _Periodstarte_ was a german word, which it is not, rhe first and the third sentence are incorrect.

Comment: Periodstart is just connected with work, you don't need to understand. :)

Comment: Handelt es sich vielleicht um Periodenstarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanings are all very similar, but for me the nuances are:

### sind nicht möglich

Could be done, but rules or regulations forbid it. Sounds like a polite answer from a clerk.

> Rückgaben nach 14 Tagen sind leider nicht möglich.

(eng.: Returns after 14 days are not possible.)

### sind unmöglich

Physically impossible, even if someone would be motivated to do something.

> Reisen zurück durch die Zeit sind unmöglich.

(eng.: Journeys back in time are impossible.)

"sind unmöglich" kann also be used for behavior.

> Ihr Verhalten ist unmöglich.

(eng.: Your behavior is impossible.)

### keine weiteren sind möglich

It could be done, and was already done. But now some kind of numeric limit was reached and the set of things that were accepted is full.

> Der Tanzkurs ist voll. Keine weiteren Anmeldungen sind möglich.

(eng.: The dance class is full. Not further registrations are possible.)

or a better sounding variant

> Der Tanzkurs ist voll. Weitere Anmeldungen sind nicht möglich.

Comment: Hm. Yes. I agree. However, these nuances largely depend on the actual context. For example: "Weitere Raketenstarts sind nicht möglich, weil wir keinen Treibstoff mehr haben", "Weitere Raketenstarts sind unmöglich, weil wir keinen Treibstoff mehr haben", "Keine weiteren Raketenstarts sind möglich, weil wir keinen Treibstoff mehr haben." - All three are equivalent.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: I agree

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 1):

Da unklar ist, was "Periodstarte" sein soll/sollen, hier deine Satzkonstruktionen mit richtigen Wörtern:

> Weitere Raketenstartversuche sind nicht möglich
>
> Weitere Raketenstartversuche sind unmöglich.
>
> Keine weiteren Raketenstartversuche sind möglich.

Alle drei Sätze sind technisch (= grammatisch) korrekt und **praktisch gleichbedeutend**. Jedoch würde man je nach Kontext und Stilebene möglicherweise der einen oder anderen Version den Vorzug geben. Die dritte Variante, scheint mir, ist die seltenste.

Und hier nochmals, weil's so schön ist, und zur Übung:

> Weitere Ballonfahrten sind nicht möglich.
>
> Weitere Ballonfahrten sind umöglich.
>
> Keine weiteren Ballonfahrten sind möglich.

Oder mit einem "zu-plus-Infinitv"-Satz:

> Weitere Erdbeeren zu ernten, ist nicht möglich.
>
> Weitere Erdbeeren zu ernten, ist unmöglich.
>
> Keine weiteren Erdbeeren können geerntet werden.

Allerdings wird man Variante 3 praktisch nie hören. Eher würde man sagen:

> Es können keine weiteren Erdbeeren geerntet werden.

Comment: Ich denke Antworten sollten nicht versuchen, die Frage richtig zu stellen, dazu sollte die Frage bearbeitet werden. Außerdem fragte der OP nach Unterschieden der Negierungen, ich befürchte aber auch das würde sehr breit werden.

Comment: Ich täte mir schwer, bei den drei Verneinungsformen Unterschiede in der Bedeutung zu finden. Ich lasse mich aber gerne belehren.

Comment: Und zum x-ten Mal der Hinweis, dass die Antwort auf Englisch sein sollte, da die Frage auf Englisch gestellt wurde ...

Comment: Auch das wäre ja eine klare Antwort. ;-) Allerdings gibt es eben kleine aber feine Unterschiede in den Verneinungen, die man auseinander nehmen könnte.

Comment: @Björn.  Well, I sometimes choose to answer these questions in German. Many people posting here want to learn German. Learning a language means practicing it.

Answer (score 1):

On googling *Periodstarte*, I figured out that there is a function `PERIODSTART` in a programming language. Based on the comment

> Periodstart is just connected with work, you don't need to understand. :)

that you left below your question, I conclude that the word *Periodstart* in your sentences might refer to this function name and that you intend to use its plural form.

If this is true, however, this would change the situation. Function names of a programming language should always be written as they are defined, and they should never be inflected. The reason is that you never know if someone else defines a function `PERIODSTARTE`, and then you would be in trouble when you want to distinguish this from the plural form of `PERIODSTART` (or any other inflected form of it). To make clear that you talk about the call of a function with the name `PERIODSTART`, you can use one of the following expressions:

> - Aufruf von PERIODSTART
> - Aufruf der Funktion PERIODSTART
> - PERIODSTART-Aufruf

Regarding your sentences, you could write something like this:

> Weitere *PERIODSTART-Aufrufe* sind nicht möglich.
>
> Weitere *PERIODSTART-Aufrufe* sind unmöglich.
>
> Es sind keine weiteren *PERIODSTART-Aufrufe* möglich.